# How do I make the Windows 8 press-and-hold rectangle go away?

Tags: delphi, windows-8, contextmenu, delphi-xe2

If you press and hold a textbox on a touchscreen in Windows 8, a rectangle appears after some time. Here's a picture of it:

[image: picture]

This rectangle is supposed to disappear when you release your finger. The context menu will now appear. (See Notepad for example.)

In a Delphi program, however, the rectangle is still there while the context menu is visible. It won't disappear until the menu closes. You can try this with a new VCL app with a TMemo.

How do I solve this?

Delphi still uses pre-Windows 8 UI events (ie. no WM_Pointer), but everything works fine except for this issue.

Comment: Did you went through the entire set of control's properties? There should be some setting you're missing for press-and-hold kind of event.

Comment: Using Delphi long ago... May be it is possible to redraw your control (SetRedraw or somehow) before menu pop up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem goes away if you include toPenTapFeedback in Touch.TabletOptions.